# Could using different packages cause a contradiction for the compiler?

Tags: packages, incompatibility, preamble

If I am writing a pdf with LaTeX, 
I would like to use commands from different packages for figures or tables or what so ever ... and I just use all the packages i need, could this lead to a contradiction or errors while compilation ?

For example:

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
```

or

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Some packages are "fragile" in that they need to be loaded before/after others. So, in that sense, yes, just "loading a bunch of packages" could be problematic. More specifically, the load order is important. Most notably, the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) requires some loading finesse. See [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Some packages cannot be loaded more than once with different options, otherwise it may cause an "option clash."  This can be fixed sometimes using `\PassOptionsToPackage{<option>}{<package>}`, which passes specific options to packages when it is loaded by another package, possibly avoid conflicts.

Comment: "Some packages" is a bit strange: *no* package can be loaded more than once with different options, with the only exception of `fontenc`. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

yes it could, because you are using babel with different option sets

maybe you should use:

```
\usepackage[ngerman, english, dutch]{babel}
```

instead.